# Function Import from another file runs part of script not in the function although module is not "main"

Tags: python-3.x, function, import, network-programming

Importing a function from another python file causes the entire script to run. The variables necessary for the function to run are all provided in the new main file. Example

```
`####Main Script

from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from push_command import command_push

password="password"
switch_list=["random_device"]
command="show interfaces status"
command_push(commands=command)

####push_command Script

from netmiko import ConnectHandler
from netbox_pull import retreive_inventory

password="password"
switch_list= retreive_inventory()
command="show interfaces Fa1/1"
def command_push(commands):
  for switch in switch_list:
    network_host = {
                "device_type": "cisco_ios",
                "host": switch,
                "username": "user",
                "password": password,
                }
            with ConnectHandler(**network_host) as net_connect:
                output = net_connect.send_command(commands)
                print(output)
                net_connect.disconnect()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    command_push(commands=command)`
```

The issue I have is when I run the Main Script, I can see the retreive_inventory function is also run which is not part of the command_push function which I explicitly called. Essentially the entire push_command script is run. It however does not use the command variable - "show interfaces Fa1/1" but the one on the Main script "show interfaces status" proving the push_command module name is not "main" when Main script is run.
This results in not being able to use a separate inventory as the switch_list is always overridden

I understand there are dependencies for the command_push function but all needed variables are provided in Main Script. I also tried removing the switch_list variable call from the push_command file but that just resulted in a variable not found error when Main script is run.